# Display a response from a Fetch with HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, response, fetch-api

My goal is to display some data on a webpage that I have obtained with a Fetch using HTML.

My Fetch (which works) looks like this

```
<script>
  let response = fetch(
    "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?per_page=100&venue.city=boston&client_id=MYAPIKEY"
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => console.log(response.events[0].title));
</script>
```

The code works and logs a response to the console as I've requested.  Now, I'd like to show some of the response on my webpage.

My attempts have looked something like this

```
<center><h2 id="response"></h2></center>    
<script>
      let response = fetch(
        "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?per_page=100&venue.city=boston&client_id=MYAPIKEY"
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => console.log(response.events[0].title))
        .then((response) => {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = response.events[0].title;
        });
    </script>
```

Context and details:

- I've done some mobile dev, but I'm a noob with even basic HTML/JS interaction on web so there are some holes in my knowledge here
- I'll be implementing this code injection as a code block on a Squarespace (Adirondack template, Adirondack family) but I don't think the Squarespace context should matter (the Fetch works just fine, and the code injection has been displaying other things just fine)
- Error from my attempt: `VM22305 about:srcdoc:8 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined`
- I'm not committed to any particular way of displaying, I'm just trying to get the ball rolling by seeing something on the page

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `.then()` callback where you log the response information does not return a value. If you just delete that `.then()` it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy.  I guess I don't have enough points on SO to be able to upvote your comment but your input was very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `then` is console logging and returning nothing (console.log returns `undefined`), so in the next `then` statement the `response` is `undefined`.

Change your code to:

```
<center><h2 id="response"></h2></center>    
<script>
      let response = fetch(
        "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?per_page=100&venue.city=boston&client_id=MYAPIKEY"
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.events[0].title);
          return response;
        })
        .then((response) => {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = response.events[0].title;
        });
</script>
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Elias.  From your answer and @Pointy's comment I can see that I can work with the data by either returning a value and working with what has been returned, or working more directly by deleting the second `.then()`

Answer (score 2):

If you want a chain of thens, you need to return a promise to the next one, like this:

```js
let response = fetch(
        "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?per_page=100&venue.city=boston&client_id=MYAPIKEY"
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = response.events[0].title;
        });
```